# Read whole node from Firebase Database

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Categories:

[image: Categories]

Database:

[image: Database]

I am trying to read the whole selected nodes (categories) and then filter through them and return them in a cloud callable function. How can I get all the data and then filter through it? When I try to log the array, it is empty.

```
exports.getRecipes = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall((data, context) => {

    categories = data.categories;



    eventsData = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        admin.database().ref(categories[i]).once('value', (data) => {
            eventsData.push(data.val());
        });
    }

    console.log(eventsData);


    return "hello";

});
```

Is there any other way getting the whole node with admin.database().ref(), without .once()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase (and most modern cloud APIs) asynchronously, and while the data is being loaded the rest of your code continues to run. This is easiest to see if you add some logging to your code:

```
console.log("Before starting to load data")

for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    admin.database().ref(categories[i]).once('value', (data) => {
        console.log("Got data")
    });
}

console.log("After starting to load data")
```

When you run this code, the output is:

> Before starting to load data
>
> After starting to load data
>
> Got data
>
> Got data
>
> ...

This is probably the order that you expected the output to be in, but it explains why your `console.log(eventsData)` shows an empty array: by the time you log the array, none of the data has been loaded yet and `eventsData.push(data.val())` hasn't run.

---

The solution for this is always the same: any code that needs the data from the asynchronous call, needs to either be directly inside the callback, be called from there, or be otherwise synchronized.

Since you're loading multiple nodes we'll use `Promise.all` here to wait for all of those nodes to have been loaded.

```
exports.getRecipes = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const categories = data.categories;
    const eventsData = Promise.all(categories.map((category) => {
        return admin.database().ref(categories[i]).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
            return snapshot.val();
        });
    });

    return eventsData;
});
```

Since we now return a promise, Cloud Functions will wait for that promise to resolve, and then return the resulting value to the caller.

I recommend learning more about promises and asynchronous behavior at:

- The Firebase documentation on terminating functions: [Sync, async, and promises](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).
- Doug's video series on [Learn JavaScript Promises (Pt.1) with HTTP Triggers in Cloud Functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA)
- The MDN pages on [Asynchronous JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous)